# What does "First thing, E" mean? How do I use it appropriately?

Tags: meaning

This guy is saying (https://youtu.be/4kuhQzbc2Tw?t=54)

> First thing, E: "What are these types of words?"

I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ACYBGNTnCrPMjWWLmltZTp-SYdFQazW8fQ%3A1581823000310&ei=GLRIXujGEsX4-gSghL24CA&q=what%20does%20%22First%20thing%2C%20E%22%20mean&oq=what%20does%20%22First%20thing%2C%20E%22%20mean&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30j0i8i10i30j0i8i30.38432.38432..38786...0.0..0.704.2205.3-1j0j2j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.lhVEYRKj18M&ved=0ahUKEwjosp_wjdXnAhVFvJ4KHSBCD4cQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) and found lots of people use this phrase as well. what does that mean? How do I use it appropriately?

I guess the "E" in the above and below are the same one, a virtual guy, designed to help understand the lesson.

same video another time stamp (https://youtu.be/4kuhQzbc2Tw?t=351)

> So, my friend, Mr. E, was drunk and I had to sort him out.

Comment: Take a closer look at those google results, and see if you really think lots of people are using "first thing, e" as a phrase.

Comment: The snake on his whiteboard is called “E” (for English I suppose). He says things like, “The first thing E will tell you is...”

Comment: @OrbitalAussie  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.